# Using downloaded sample projects with a missing .xcodeproj

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to learn Obj-C but when I download sample projects, the .xcodeproj file seems to be missing on all the examples I download. Not quite sure why, but I'm stuck. A few questions (which overlap):

1. How do I open these projects to run them if the .xcodeproj file is missing?
2. How do I turn these downloaded examples into projects I can use?
3. Is there some fundamental reason why it seems to be standard practice NOT to include the .xcodeproj file?

Comment: `projectname.xcodeproj` is a folder, not a file. It contains the `pbxproj`, and other files.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to open a project without an .xcodeproj. This directory contains several compulsory infos like :

- list of files, resources of the project,
- compilation options,
- etc.

Comment: Right. So if the file is missing, is there a simple way to bring in a project, other than adding every single file manually - classes, nibs, ... seems like there should be a quick way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting these samples from? Is it possible that xcodeproj files are hidden on your filesystem? If there really isn't an .xcodeproj file, then it's not too hard to make your own and drag in the source files.

Comment: I could look up the site, but there definitely were no .xcodeproj in the couple of samples I downloaded. They were unzipped, so nowhere to look except in the folder created. You said it's not hard to make your own and drag in the source files. I'm asking how to do that. I know it's dumb, but I'm thinking there's an easy way I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: No it's not dumb. 1) Xcode menu->file->new project, then pick the kind of app you want to make. 2) on the left, you'll see yellow folder icons. Drag the code into the top one, it probably has the same name as the project you just created. 3) click 'Run'. 4) ? 5) Profit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using git command lines to clone repositories.

However, if you use XCode's integrated source control features to work with existing projects you can open the project and you will find the xcodeproj in your source code directory.

To do this, launch XCode, choose "Connect to repository", specify the location (for example: https://github.com/insurgentgames/Alphabet-Blocks.git), hit 'Clone', then Open Project.